# How link a subdomain to the different server ip?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, debian, web-administration

I have my primary domain, bogdan.co, that is linked via NS records to my hoster (hts.ru). Now I want to create a sub-domain cloud.bogdan.co, that should be hosted at my owncloud server on specified port: 91.122.34.89:2207. How can I make this? Godaddy (my domain provider) allows me to add only IP-address of my server in Host Names for my sub-domain. But I also need to point my sub-domain to my 2207 port. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add SVR record in DNS configuration.
Into GoDaddy Site:

1. Select the domain name you want to use, click Text Icon (Settings) and select Manage DNS.
2. At the bottom of the Records section, click Add and select SRV from the menu.
3. Complete the following fields:

   - Service — Enter the service name of this SRV record. The name should begin with an underscore, such as _ldap, _ftp, or _smtp.
   - Protocol — Enter the protocol the service uses. The name should begin with an underscore, such as _tcp or _udp.
   - Name — Enter the host name or domain name the SRV links to, such as server1. If you want to link the record to your domain name, type @.
   - Priority — Select the priority for the SRV record. For multiple records that have the same Name and Service, clients use the priority number to determine which Target to contact first.
   - Weight — Select the weight of the SRV record. For multiple records that have the same Name, Service, and Priority, clients use the weight number to determine which Target to contact first.
   - Port — Enter the port number for the service, such as 80 or 21.
   - TTL — Select how long the server should cache the information.
4. Click save

site: https://it.godaddy.com/help/add-an-srv-record-19216

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).